# Rails - how to incorporate 'quantity' bookings using counter_cache and update correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, rails-activerecord

I'm building an events app using Rails and have added a counter_cache association between my Event and Booking models in order to capture the number of bookings made on each event.

How do I get the counter_cache to update correctly when more than one booking can be made at any one time? At the moment, each time a booking is made, regardless of how many spaces for an event are required (3,4,5 etc) , the counter_cache will only increment by one. This creates an inaccuracy in number of bookings Vs number of spaces available (and total_amount ).

Is it as simple as -

```
def my_booking
    event.bookings_count * booking.quantity
end
```

If so, where / how do I call this in my MVC process?

This is my Booking Model with set_booking method (for payments), but should a method be in here or in my Event model ?

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :event, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :user
  before_create :set_booking_number


  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
  validates :total_amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

  validate(:validate_booking)
  #validate(:validate_availability)

  def set_booking_number
    self.booking_number = "MAMA" + '- ' + SecureRandom.hex(4).upcase
  end

  def set_booking

        if self.event.is_free?
          self.total_amount = 0
          save!
        else
          self.total_amount = event.price_pennies * self.quantity
          begin
            charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
              amount: total_amount,
              currency: "gbp",
              source: stripe_token, 
              description: "Booking created for amount #{total_amount}")
            self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
            save!
          rescue Stripe::CardError => e
            # if this fails stripe_charge_id will be null, but in case of update we just set it to nil again
            self.stripe_charge_id = nil
            # we check in validatition if nil

          end

        end


  end

      def validate_booking

        # stripe_charge_id must be set for not free events
        unless self.event.is_free?
          return !self.stripe_charge_id.nil?
        end
      end



end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to implement your own caching method.

```
Class Event
  def update_bookings_count(amount)
   update_column(:bookings_count, "bookings_count + #{amount}")
  end
end
```

After the booking was successful call:

```
event.update_bookings_count(quantity)
```

And just use event.bookings_count when you need the count.

Another option might be to look into this gem: https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture#totaling-instead-of-counting it seems to do what you want.

Comment: You're right about that Gem but what if I've already implemented a migration to incorporate counter_cache. I'm pretty sure it can't be overidden.

Comment: You can create a new migration that drops the old column. 

remove_column :table_name, :column_name